# Time::Piece put together date and time of two different objects

Tags: perl, datetime, time

I have created two Time::Piece objects. I would like to do a concatenation of the date of object1 to the time of object2, that is
`object1= 2014-05-09
object2= 12:34:40
object3= 2014-05-09T12:34:40`

Does anybody has a hint, how to do this with Time::Piece?
Thankx!

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you are asking about.  I've never heard of `Time::Piece`, but that's likely because you're using a language that I don't use.

Answer (score 0):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) isn't a particularly clever class. Most of its methods are about getting at its components in different formats.

But you can get the date from $object1

```
my $date = $object1->date;
```

And you can get the time from $object2

```
my $time = $object2->time;
```

If you only want the new time as a string, then your job is done.

```
my $object3 = $date . 'T' . $time;
```

But if you want a new Time::Piece object, you can use the class's `strptime` method to create one.

```
my $object3 = Time::Piece->strptime($date . 'T' . $time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
```